# Call a JavaScript function when closing IE browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am attempting to call a function when the browser closes which I've been able to do successfully with Chrome, but can't get it to work on IE. I can get a dialog box to show up for IE, and if I do that, it works and calls the function.. however this would be a bad experience, so I'd like to just call the function.

Here is the code that works for Chrome:

```
    $window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
        return analyticsTrack();
    }, false);
```

Here is the code that causes a dialog box to pop up on IE

```
    $window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
        (e || window.event).returnValue = "Close";
        analyticsTrack();
    }, false);
```

Any ideas?

Note: This code is in Angular

Comment: what does `analyticsTrack()` return? Read docs for beforeunload...must return string or not return anything

Comment: Just tried making sure it returns a string.. but that still doesn't work on IE

Comment: Is it an Ajax call? It is not going to happen because when the page exits it kills any http requests that are open. So it is a race between the ajax call and the closing routine.

Comment: It is an Ajax call but seems to be working fine in Chrome

Comment: Have you tried `return undefined`?

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for the response. Just tried this but didn't work